# java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am getting stack traces like this on force close of a soundboard app. I am still trying to decipher what it is saying. I'm really new at this.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.squeaker.app.main$37.onClick(main.java:447)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8818)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4701)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
```

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors). Ultimately, you'll want to look at what's on line 447 of your `main.java` class.

Comment: We can't help you unless you post some code, preferably a shortest, self-contained example that reproduces the problem.  But in general terms it is telling you the sequence of function calls that lead to the error.  And a NullPointerException is telling you that the code is trying to use a variable that is not referring to an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the 447th line on com.squeaker.app.main$37.onClick

One of the object is null and your code is trying to perform something on a null object. Most likely if you are calling methods in this line like:

```
someObject.someMethod();
```

It means that someObject is null. Then go back and figure out why this someObject is null

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I'm going to check it out again later today. I thought my app was simple enough nothing could go wrong, but this is killing me.